# Echo string before redirect

Tags: php

How to echo some text and after that do redirection?
Text must show on this page, before redirection.

I think that isn't possibble in this way, but maybe anybody have idea how to do that.

I tried:

```
<?php
echo "<SetViewMode>512</SetViewMode>";
header("Location: sport.php");
exit();
?>
```

and this

```
<?php
<SetViewMode>512</SetViewMode>
header("Location: sport.php");
exit();
?>
```

But doesn't work because header already sent...

I understand error, but I really want this text before redirect.
Sport.php referer must have this text `<SetViewMode>512</SetViewMode>`
If I do redirect withot `<SetViewMode>512</SetViewMode>`, sport.php doesn't know what is viewmode was.

I can't add this `<SetViewMode>512</SetViewMode>` in sport.php code, because this doesn't work. Must be in referer page.

Maybe anybode have better solution?

Comment: If you only need to carry data over to `sport.php`, then why don't you set the view-mode in a query string attached to the location url, e.g. `header("Location: sport.php?viewmode=512");`. In `sport.php` you can read the value from `$_GET['viewmode'];`

Comment: You're saying "Sport.php" looks at the user's referrer and then fetches that page to read data on it? That's very unusual, and very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

use a refresh redirect in the header

```
echo $theMsg;
header("refresh:$seconds;url=$url");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript can solve your problem:

```
<SetViewMode>512</SetViewMode>

<script>window.location.href='sport.php';</script>
```